# Error "The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer."

Tags: flutter

I try other ways. but not working. Please help me. Thanks

```
class AppBottom extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  final String appName;
  const AppBottom({Key? key, required this.appName}) : super(key: key); // 
  @override
  _AppBottomState createState() => _AppBottomState();
}

class _AppBottomState extends State<AppBottom> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> _widgetOptions = [
    Home(appName: widget.appName), * error: The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer.*
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error mentions, you cannot access `widget` when the `_AppBottomState` object is created. Instead you'll have to override the `initState` method to initialize the `_widgetOptions` list.

```
class _AppBottomState extends State<AppBottom> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> _widgetOptions;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _widgetOptions = [
      Home(appName: widget.appName),
    ];
    super.initState();
  }
  
}
```